Vuex state not updating from fetch
const fetchCartItems = () => {
  store.dispatch('cart/fetchCartItems'); 
};

const cartItems = computed(() => store.getters['cart/cartItems']);

console.log('Products  is : ', cartItems.value);

watch(cartItems, (newValue) => {
  console.log('Cart items updated:', newValue);
});
onMounted(() => {
  fetchCartItems(); // Učitaj proizvode kada se komponenta montira
});

return {
  cartItems,
};

Everything works in vuex. It downloads data from the server, but cartItems is always empty. Therefore, I cannot transfer the data to the template.
I get all the values. Watch see change to state. But it doesn't transfer to vue.
Where am I wrong?

You've not given enough information.  No where in your code is a fetch call made nor are any values shown being assigned to cartItems.  Assuming this happens in your store, share the relevant store code.  Please read How to Ask and specifically how to create MCVE

const cartItems = computed(() => store.getters['cart/cartItems']);
takes value from vuex
with return forwards the template?
watch(cartItems, (newValue)  registers a value change in vuex  and show in consol

console.log('Products  is : ', cartItems.value); is emty

I understand what the code shown is doing.  I'll rephrase the important part of my previous comment: the code inside your vuex store needs to be shared.  edit your question with the code, don't put code in comments.  if there's a problem, it's in your vuex code, not the component where you call vuex.  cartItems is being assigned some value from a fetch.  we need to see the fetch.  we need to see the new value being assigned.  the code shown in your question so far shows none of that.  your comment added literally no new information.
